# Woocommerce won't add products to cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm not sure what I did to break this because it was working fine for a while but I can no longer add products to the WooCommerce cart in the site I'm working on. On every attempt I get the "Please choose product options" message in return.

I have a selected price for each variable yet it still doesn't work. I'm thinking it could have something to do with the quantity selector of that could possibly not be going through.

There may also be a conflict with some jQuery libraries and I have been told to check for errors but I have tried countless times to approach this and I just can't find the solution and this really needs to be fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: what web server are you using?

Comment: I'm using Bluehost for my server

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it. It was a caching issue on my host. Once they excluded certain sessions/cookies to be cached (on server side) all started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Did it work okay before you upgraded to the latest version of Woocommerce?

```
<!-- WooCommerce Version -->
<meta name="generator" content="WooCommerce 2.0.3" />
```

Woo recently did a major upgrade to their ecommerce engine, and it may need tweaking to work with your current theme.

One thing you can test is to temporarily switch to a different theme which is known to work with the up-to-date woocommerce, e.g. http://www.woothemes.com/products/mystile/ which is a free theme from the Woo folks themselves.

Comment: It wasn't working before the update and it didn't work after I updated it either. I ran the update and then had to design everything to fit my needs once more and right after that they added another minor update on top of the major one that I had to uninstall because it messed up my site once again. I'm running on too tight of a schedule to go through all of that again.

I'm honestly pretty sure I made some mistake along the way and screwed with some kind of jQuery thing that's causing a conflict of sorts

Comment: Any word on how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, did you try installing and temporarily switching to an unmodified free theme like 'mystile'? If that fixes the problem then you know to start poking around your theme options or the files in the theme folder.

Comment: Yeah I reverted back to the default 2012 theme, there is definitely something wrong with my modified Max Magazine theme. I've been trying to track down the problem for over a month and still can't figure it out but I am very new to all of this.